# torch dataset error -- 'numpy.int32' is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, dataset

I'm preparing a set of medical imaging volumes and segmentation masks to be input into a multi-label segmentation neural network for training. I am recieving the following error message when I attempt to load my 5D tensors into a torch TensorDataset:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (path/project.py), line 122, in <module>
    train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(timg, tmask)
  File (path/dataset.py), line 365, in __init__
    assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
  File (path/dataset.py)", line 365, in <genexpr>
    assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors), "Size mismatch between tensors"
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not callable
```

My original assumption was that the size mismatch was due to the difference in the dimensions of my tensors -- the feature tensor had dimensions 60x128x128x64x1 and the label tensor had dimensions 60x128x128x64x5. However, making the shape and size of these tensors equal has not resolved the issue. My other theory was that the issue was related to this line of code:

```
def transt(list):
    array = np.asarray(list, ->np.int32<-)
```

changing the dtype did not seem to have an effect. I also tried casting the tensor into different dtypes, again to seemingly no effect on the problem.

Attached is the code. Unsure of how to proceed and any advice would be very appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from VNet import VNet
import Layers
import torchvision
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()

# Setting path
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(dirname, 'Liver_MR_Dataset')

# Loading images/masks
img_list = []
gall_list = []
IVC_list = []
kidney_list = []
liver_list = []
rib_list = []
os.chdir(path + '/Image')
image_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/Image'))
for image in image_path:
    img = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    img_list.append(img)
print(len(img_list))
train_img = img_list[:60]
print(len(train_img))
val_img = img_list[60:]
print(len(val_img))

os.chdir(path + '/Gall')
gall_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/Gall'))
for image in gall_path:
    mask = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    gall_list.append(mask)
train_gall = gall_list[:60]
val_gall = gall_list[60:]

os.chdir(path + '/IVC')
IVC_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/IVC'))
for image in IVC_path:
    mask = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    IVC_list.append(mask)
train_IVC = IVC_list[:60]
val_IVC = IVC_list[60:]

os.chdir(path + '/Kidney')
kidney_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/Kidney'))
for image in kidney_path:
    mask = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    kidney_list.append(mask)
train_kidney = kidney_list[:60]
val_kidney = kidney_list[60:]

os.chdir(path + '/Liver')
liver_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/Liver'))
for image in liver_path:
    mask = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    liver_list.append(mask)
train_liver = liver_list[:60]
val_liver = liver_list[60:]

os.chdir(path + '/Rib')
rib_path = sorted(os.listdir(path + '/Rib'))
for image in rib_path:
    mask = nib.load(image).get_fdata()
    rib_list.append(mask)
train_rib = rib_list[:60]
val_rib = rib_list[60:]

os.chdir(path)
# Transformations
def transt(list):
    array = np.asarray(list, np.int32)
    resize = np.resize(array, [60,128,128,64])
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(resize)
    return tensor

def transv(list):
    array = np.asarray(list, np.int32)
    resize = np.resize(array, [7,128,128,64])
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(resize)
    return tensor

tgall = transt(train_gall)
vgall = transv(val_gall)
tIVC = transt(train_IVC)
vIVC = transv(val_IVC)
tkidney = transt(train_kidney)
vkidney = transv(val_kidney)
tliver = transt(train_liver)
vliver = transv(val_liver)
trib = transt(train_rib)
vrib = transv(val_rib)
timg4d = transt(train_img)
vimg4d = transv(val_img)

timg = tf.stack([timg4d, timg4d, timg4d, timg4d, timg4d], axis=4)
print(timg.shape)
print(timg.size)
vimg = tf.stack([timg4d, timg4d, timg4d, timg4d, timg4d], axis=4)
tmask = tf.stack([tgall, tIVC, tkidney, tliver, trib], axis=4)
print(tmask.shape)
print(tmask.size)
vmask = tf.stack([vgall, vIVC, vkidney, vliver, vrib], axis=4)

# Create Datasets
train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(timg, tmask)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=60)

#val_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(vimg, vmask)
#val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=60)
```

Comment: list is a reserved keyword, it is not smart to name variables as list.

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a tuple, `all(tensors[0].size[0] == tensor.size[0] for tensor in tensors),`